# Change in android app to use adsense in exsisting app that using admob

Tags: android

I am using admob in my android app.Should i need to change in my code to receive ads from Google AdSense?

Answer (score 1):

No.

If your app is eligible for AdSense ads, an option will be available in your Admob dashboard under Manage>App Settings that allows you to backfill the inventory with Adsense ads. There is no code needed for this.